# CSS - Triangle down

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How do I create an arrow down (triangle) when hovering over a link?

something like the result tab on CodePen, see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

I was trying to create the triangle by following the the tutorial above, but no luck

```
 a{
  background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 5px;
    display block
  }

  a:hover {background: green;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but this could be the answer:

css:

```
.arrow_down_on_hover{
  position: relative;
}
.arrow_down_on_hover:before{
  content: "";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  display: none;
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
  bottom: -20px;
}
.arrow_down_on_hover:hover:before{
  display: block;
}
```

html:

```
<a class="arrow_down_on_hover" href="#!">hover me</a>
```

example:

http://codepen.io/eboye/pen/zBYzav

Answer (score 1):

The code below it is just by following the tutorial you linked in your question,

but since you are using a link `a` you have to make it as block level by setting it `display:block` due to be an inline element

```css
a {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  display:block
}
a:hover {
  border-top: 20px solid green
}
```

```html
<a href="">Hover me</a>
```

---

If this is just a matter of show/hide the triangle when hovering some link, a better approach would be using the pseudo elements `::before`/`::after` along with unicode down arrow symbol

```css
a:hover::after {
  content: "\25bc";
  color: green
}
```

```html
<a href="">Hover me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
a:hover .arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<a>link<div class="arrow-down"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just use [the arrow down symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm):

```css
a::after {
  content: '\25bc'; 
  color: red;
}

a:hover::after {
  color: green; 
}
```

```html
<a>Hover me!</a>
```

You can also specify the same character in HTML instead of CSS, by using the entity: `&#x25bc;`.